# Autheticate via SAML and create token in API

Tags: php, laravel, saml, saml-2.0

I am working on SAML authentication for my application which has the following architecture.

Frontend application written in Laravel - does not handle authentication
Backed API also written in Laravel which handles authentication

What I have now is a login form that has a login with SAML button which uppon clicked redirects to a Microsoft page and redirects a callback page on the frontend application with information from the saml request.

Now I need to authenticate the user and create a token, then make a session in the frontend application.
Since I was using SAML, I have no password to do a traditional authenticate.
This would mean that I need some API to which I pass *some* info from SAML to be able to check whether that email exists in the db and subsequently created a token.

But since this API is public, I can't just pass an email because that would allow someone to guess it.
How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

> redirects a callback page on the frontend application with information
>   from the saml request

the information from the SAML request is your authentication event. The user has authenticated to your application by logging in at their Identity Provider (Microsoft page) and returning to your application with their SAML attributes.

If it was a traditional authentication with a username/password, once the password matches, you would create a session for them. In this case the password check was done by Microsoft and told your application it was successful by sending the SAML `Response` to your callback.

If you parse the SAML `Response` and extract the attributes you can use one of them to create the session. Something persistent such as [eduPersonTargetedID](https://www.switch.ch/aai/support/documents/attributes/edupersontargetedid/) which will always be the same value for that user will let you create their session. When they logout and log back in, that `eduPersonTargetedID` will have the same value in their SAML `Response`.

SAML `Response` samples are available [here](https://www.samltool.com/generic_sso_res.php).